# oncomplete, pass recordId variable into URL

Tags: visualforce, javascript, oncomplete

How can I replace my **oncomplete** in the **apex:commandButton** to have a variable in it? Specifically, instead of going to the Account list I'm trying to get the whole page to reload for the record it's on (i.e. /lightning/r/Account/`recordId`/view). This Visualforce Page is embedded within a tab on the Account object and it creating related Contact records. The standard **window.top.location.reload()** doesn't seem to be refreshing the entire page, just the VF form. **window.top.location.replace()** seems to work, but I'm failing in trying to get a variable in there. I think I'm missing something obvious.

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="AddMultiplePets" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" lightningStylesheets="true">
   <head>
      <apex:slds />
   </head>
   <style>
      table tr:nth-child(4n-1), table tr:nth-child(4n)  {background: #ccc;}
      table tr {background: #eee;}
      .fieldLabel {font-weight: 800; font-size:medium;}
      body textarea, .slds-vf-scope textarea, body input[type="text"], .slds-vf-scope input[type="text"], body select, body select[size="0"], body select[size="1"], .slds-vf-scope select, .slds-vf-scope select[size="0"], .slds-vf-scope select[size="1"] {
      border: 1px solid rgb(105 105 105);}
   </style>
   <div class="slds-scope">
      <apex:form >
         <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}"  />
         <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}"  />
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!petList}" var="pet">
               <apex:facet name="header">
                  <apex:commandLink action="{!insertRow}">
                     <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">
                        <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
                           <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-reverse">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                 xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#add">
                              </use>
                           </svg>
                        </svg>
                        ADD ROW 
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Add Row</span>
                     </button>
                     <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="index" />
                  </apex:commandLink>
               </apex:facet>
               <apex:column rowspan="2">
                  <apex:commandLink action="{!delRow}">
                     <button class="slds-button slds-button_destructive">
                        <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
                           <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-reverse">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                 xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#delete">
                              </use>
                           </svg>
                        </svg>
                        DELETE: {!rowNum}
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete Row</span>
                     </button>
                     <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="index" />
                  </apex:commandLink>
                  <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
               </apex:column>
               <apex:column >
                  <span class="fieldLabel">Species</span><br/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!pet.Species__c}"/>
               </apex:column>
               //...bunch of other columns
               <apex:column >
                  <span class="fieldLabel">Primary Living Area</span><br/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!pet.Primary_Living_Area__c}"/>
               </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <div style="text-align:center">
               <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_success" value="Create Records" action="{!insertPets}" oncomplete="window.top.location.replace('/lightning/o/Account/list?filterName=Recent)"/>
            </div>
         </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
   </div>
</apex:page>
```

**APEX Class:**

```
public class AddMultiplePets {
    Id accId;
    public List<Contact> petList {get;set;}
    public Integer rowNum {get;set;}
    public String lastNameString {get;set;}
    public List<Contact> lastNameDefault {get; set;}  
    
    public AddMultiplePets(){
            accId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
            petList = new List<Contact>();  
            petList.add(new Contact());
            lastNameDefault = [SELECT LastName FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (SELECT npe01__One2OneContact__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accId) LIMIT 1];
                for (Contact currentLastName : lastNameDefault) 
                {lastNameString = currentLastName.LastName;}
    }
    
    public void insertPets(){
        for(Contact objInt : petList){
            objInt.AccountId = accId;
            objInt.RecordTypeId = '0124P000000uNWFQA2';
            objInt.LastName = lastNameString;
        }
        insert petList;
        
    }
    
    public void insertRow(){
        petList.add(new Contact()); 
    }
    
    public void delRow(){
        rowNum = Integer.valueOf(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));
        petList.remove(rowNum);   
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I just needed to change my **oncomplete** to this:
`<apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_success" value="Create Records" action="{!insertPets}" oncomplete="window.top.location.replace('/lightning/r/Account/{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}/view')"/>`